# Magento: Paypal Express checkout button not working

Tags: magento-1.9, module, payment-methods, shopping-cart, paypal-express

Hope I can get some help. It seems the Paypal Express checkout is broken on a Magento store. Anytime you click on "Checkout with Paypal Express" it just reloads the shopping cart page, doesn't go to paypal's checkout like it should. And another strange thing I notice, when I go into System>Configuration>Payment Methods the "Configure" button for "Paypal Express" is grayed out and not clickable. The only way I can make it clickable is if I inspect the HTML code and change "disabled" to "enabled" in the button element.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's possible that you are being affected by the massive DDOS attack affecting the United States at the moment. Paypal is affected by the issue and it causes issues similar to what you are experiencing. If your issue persists after the attacks fully subside then I'll remove this answer.

Reference: https://krebsonsecurity.com/2016/10/ddos-on-dyn-impacts-twitter-spotify-reddit/

Reference: https://twitter.com/PayPal/status/789538481596882944?ref_src=twsrc%5Egoogle%7Ctwcamp%5Enews%7Ctwgr%5Etweet

Comment: Wow, I wasn't aware of this. Thanks a bunch for the information. I'll be checking on updates to this.

Comment: You may find that this is not the root cause of your issue, but I personally wouldn't try to troubleshoot that type of behavior until its over, since you have no easy way of knowing if the DDos is causing your issue. I've seen some strange paypal functionality today that i've never seen in years working with it.

Comment: You can use this as a reference: https://twitter.com/PayPal/status/789538481596882944?ref_src=twsrc%5Egoogle%7Ctwcamp%5Enews%7Ctwgr%5Etweet